# moving button up to the top, ignoring what's above the button.

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons. but I'm doing display:hide for one button. below that hidden button, I have one more button. I want that button to be located where that hidden button is. How do I do this with css?

```
 <input type="submit" value="{% trans "login" %}" style="display:hidden" />

  <input type="submit" value="{% trans "login" %}" />
```

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you had a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and some more context...

Comment: @KyleBradley just asking if there's a way to do it in css?

Comment: absolute positioning removes the element from the flow of elements on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="{% trans "login" %}" style="display:hidden; position:absolute;" />

<input type="submit" value="{% trans "login" %}" />
```

Comment: like the answer below, which might be better suited for your needs, display: none also removes the element from the flow of the document

Answer (score 0):

`display:none` not `display:hidden`

Also, use different sets of quotes. You can use double quotes *inside* single quotes (or vice versa), but you cannot use double quotes inside double quotes.

```html
<input type="submit" value='{% trans "login" %}' style="display:none;" />
<input type="submit" value='{% trans "login" %}' />
```

Also, instead of inline styling (where you add a `style=""` attribute to the element, you should use a class and have external CSS, such as:

```
<input class="hid" type="submit" value='{% trans "login" %}' />
<input type="submit" value='{% trans "login" %}' />

<style>
    .hid{display:none;}
</style>
```

Doing that allows you to do this:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2s6najm4/)